# HIVE - date_format( your_date_column, '%Y-%m-%d %H' )

Tags: hive

I'm trying to achieve the MySQL equivalent of `date_format( your_date_column, '%Y-%m-%d %H' ) as my_date` in Hive. I've tried a few options from [Hive date formatting](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/date-functions-in-hive.html) but can't get the format right. I haven't found anything that has helped me yet.

Could I please request someone who may have already bumped into this situation or knows how to do it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by using `concat(substr(your_date_column,1,13), ':00')`

In case the date column has a reserved keyword such as `timestamp` as in my case, this works - concat(substr(`timestamp`,1,13), ':00')

Answer (score 7):

Recent version of Hive have a [`date_format()` function](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), it just uses java formatting codes instead of C.  Try `date_format(your_date_column, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH')`

Answer (score 2):

To convert date to given string format you have to use `from_unixtime()` function of hive

`from_unixtime(bigint unixtime[, string format])` converts the number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC) to a string representing the timestamp of that moment in the current system time zone.

The sample input and output can be seen from below image: 
[image]

The final query is

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd HH') as my_date from table1;
```

where table1 is the table name present in my hive database.

I hope this help you to achieve `date_format( your_date_column, '%Y-%m-%d %H' )` !!!

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a column 'birth_day_H' in your table which is in string format,
you should use the following query to filter using birth_day_H

```
date_Format(birth_day_H, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH')
```

You can use it in a query in the following way

```
select * from yourtable
where 
date_Format(birth_day_H, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH') = '2019-04-16 10';
```